# Does Re-Index Tree command in Content Editor always cause a recreation of Solr documents

Tags: solr, content-search, sitecore-commerce

I'm using the "Re-Index Tree" button in the Content Editor (Developer toolbar). I run a query in Solr admin just after to examine the indexed document and for some reason, the _indextimestamp property of the document does not seem to update.

Is there logic in Sitecore or Solr which means the document only gets updated IF there is a change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Mostly, yes.**

I found that for regular master/web indexes the update does indeed happen irrespective of whether changes have been made. So re-indexing a tree, should see the _indextimestamp change for any affected items.

**But not always**

For Sitecore Commerce (in 9.0, at least) performing a "Re-index Tree" only seems to result in an actual update if changes to commerce items have taken place. In the logs I found the message

```
Checking for entities to index in list 'SellableItemsIncrementalIndexMaster'.
```

so I presume that no matter what you do in Sitecore, nothing will update in the indexes, unless you make some Commerce Catalog changes.

Comment: I was about to answer this, because im pretty sure it always update the document regardless if the item changed or not

Comment: @AhmedOkour Do feel free to add an answer!